# Obtener el Nombre del Navegador

Tags: javascript, navegador-web

actualmente estoy creando un script para enviar un informe de error de una aplicación determinada, para ello necesito obtener los siguientes parametros:

- Nombre del Navegador
- Versión
- Sistema Operativo donde Corre

Estuve utilizando algunas propiedades pero no todas funcionan de la manera que se esperaria, necesito alguna funcion que obtenga dicho datos sea cual sea el navegador o al menos que funcione bien para Firefox, Chrome, IE y Edge.

Gracias

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript si no este Fiddle está mejor http://jsfiddle.net/ChristianL/AVyND/

Comment: Estimado @Ricardo, el tema que tocas es delicado, tanto así que **jQuery** (librería para desarrollo multi plataforma) desde la version 1.9 removió el soporte para leer información del _navigator.userAgent_, considero de mi parte un error darte ejemplo de como hacerlo ya que esto podría cambiar (y dejar de funcionar tu aplicacion con el tiempo), lo mas acertado que puedes hacer es soportarte en una libreria dedicada a la detección de  características y nuevas características en los exploradores web tal es el caso de [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/).